# MYSQL- SELF REFERENCING FOREIGN KEY

Tags: mysql, sql, select, join, self-join

I have a self-referencing foreign key **(reportsTo)** which refers to **emp_id** of the same table

I want to find out the employees who reports to their seniors.

I ran the following query

```
mysql> SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(emp_name SEPARATOR ',') as Employees,reportsTo from employees GROUP BY reportsTo;
+-----------------------------+-----------+
| Employees                   | reportsTo |
+-----------------------------+-----------+
| ram,ham,anir                |         1 |
| abhi,kuanl,rakesh,raja,rama |         2 |
| vicky,sam                   |         3 |
| dhanapal,naina              |         4 |
+-----------------------------+-----------+
```

BUT IN THE **REPORTSTO** COLUMN, I want the persons name whom they are reporting to.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use **SELF JOIN** to fetch the name of the reporting to employees.

Try this:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(e.emp_name SEPARATOR ',') AS Employees, 
       e.reportsTo, e1.emp_name
FROM employees e 
INNER JOIN employees e1 ON e.reportsTo = e1.emp_id 
GROUP BY e.reportsTo;
```